# BeautifulSoup неправильно находит тег

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

На странице присутствуют два тега div - `<div class="r 1">` и `<div class="r">` 
Этот код

```
html = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
print(html.find('div', {'class': 'r 1'}).get_text()) 
print(html.find('div', {'class': 'r'}).get_text())
```

в обоих случаях находит `<div class="r 1">`. Как получить тег `<div class="r">`?

Comment: html.find_all('div', {'class': 'r'}).get_text()        Метод find возвращает первое найденное значение